# How to add root context to spring boot application except for /login?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am working on a Spring Boot application with JSP as UI. Where I had to add a root-context `/applicationName` for the entire application except for `/login`.

I tried  to added the below code to the `application.properties`.

```
server.servlet.context-path=/applicationName
server.servlet.context-path-exclude=/login
```

but it didn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the configuration options, the context path in Spring Boot can be changed by setting a property, `server.servlet.context-path`.

Note, that it only works for Spring Boot
2.x. and above. For Spring Boot 1.x, the property is `server.context-path`.

Comment: I am using spring 2.7.2
`  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.2</version>
`
I added server.servlet.context-path=/applicationName already it added context path.
But I am don't want a context path in front of /login

Comment: What prevents you from mapping a different servlet context to `/login`?